# How to get device properties in windows in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, properties, device

In Windows, if I open Device Manager-> right click on the device -> Properties -> Details, I get {Property, Value} pairs. I want to access them in my C++ code in Visual Studio. How do I get it?

Thanks,

Comment: Which properties are you looking for specifically?

Comment: @fardjad I need to know: **matching device id**. Can you please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try SetupDi_ functions,look [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259695/en-us/) for example.

```
HDEVINFO WinDeviceHelper::getDevInfoForClass(QString devClassName,DWORD& dwCount)
{

    //DWORD dwGuids = 0;

    SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameW( qPrintableW(devClassName), 0, 0, &dwCount );

    //emit sSearchStarted(dwGuids);

    if(dwCount)
    {
        GUID* pGuids = new GUID[dwCount];

        BOOL success = SetupDiClassGuidsFromNameW( qPrintableW(devClassName), pGuids, dwCount, &dwCount );

        HDEVINFO hDevInfoSet = SetupDiGetClassDevsW( pGuids, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_PRESENT);

        delete [] pGuids;

        return hDevInfoSet;
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}
bool WinDeviceHelper::getDeviceRegistryString(HDEVINFO hDevInfoSet,SP_DEVINFO_DATA &devInfo,DWORD propertyType,QString& propValue)
{
    DWORD dwType = 0;
    DWORD requiredSize=0;
    propValue="";
    BOOL result=SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW( hDevInfoSet, &devInfo, propertyType, &dwType, NULL, NULL, &requiredSize);
    if ((result==ERROR_INVALID_DATA) || ((dwType!=REG_MULTI_SZ)&&(dwType!=REG_SZ)) || (requiredSize==0) )
    {
        return false;
        //throw std::exception(__FILE__":"__LINE__" "__FUNCDNAME__":  Error reading registry info");
    }
    size_t strSize=requiredSize/sizeof(wchar_t)+1;
    wchar_t* requestedData = new wchar_t[strSize];// буфер
    result=SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW( hDevInfoSet, &devInfo, propertyType, &dwType,reinterpret_cast<PBYTE>(requestedData), requiredSize, &requiredSize);
    if(result==TRUE )
    {
        propValue=QString::fromWCharArray(requestedData,wcslen(requestedData));
    }
    else
    {
        Logger::logError(QString("WinDeviceHelper::getDeviceRegistryString: SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryPropertyW failed with error %1").arg(GetLastError()));
    }
    delete[]requestedData;
    return (result==TRUE );

}

bool WinDeviceHelper::getVendorAndDeviceIds(HDEVINFO hDevInfoSet,SP_DEVINFO_DATA &devInfo,QString& vendorId, QString& deviceId)
{
    QString dataStr;
    if(getDeviceRegistryString(hDevInfoSet,devInfo,SPDRP_HARDWAREID,dataStr))
    {
        dataStr=dataStr.toUpper();
        QRegExp vidpid("(VID_)[0-9A-F]{4}(&PID_)[0-9A-F]{4}");
        int pos=dataStr.indexOf(vidpid);
        if(pos>=0)
        {
            vendorId=dataStr.mid(pos+4,4);
            pos+=8;
            pos+=5;
            deviceId=dataStr.mid(pos,4);
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

piece of usage

```
    DWORD dwGuids = 0;
    HDEVINFO hDevInfoSet = getDevInfoForClass(drvClass,dwGuids);
    //Logger::logTrace(QString("WinDeviceHelper::searchForPort() found %1 port drivers for type %2").arg(dwGuids).arg(drvClass));
    if(dwGuids)
    {
        BOOL bMoreItems = TRUE;
        int nIndex = 0;

        SP_DEVINFO_DATA devInfo;
        devInfo.cbSize = sizeof( SP_DEVINFO_DATA );

        while( SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo( hDevInfoSet, nIndex, &devInfo ) && ( nIndex != -1 ) )
        {
            //Logger::logTrace(QString("WinDeviceHelper::searchForPort() enumerating ports. current index: %1").arg(nIndex));
            QString iVid,iPid;
            QString fName;

            if( getVendorAndDeviceIds(hDevInfoSet,devInfo,iVid,iPid)
              enter code here

        }
    }
```

Comment: Also, is there a Microsoft link explaining what each property means (in detail)?

Comment: google properties by their names. Yes, they are in msdn, in help for functions which use them. But not in all functions so search by constant name, not by function name.

Comment: The link is now dead.