# How to Retrieve the Rollback driver node strong name?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, msdn, setupapi

I want to retrieve the Rollback driver node strong name  device property from device manager  .

Attached image for reference .

How can i do that programmatically ?

[image: enter image jhere]

Comment: done :) can u help me or suggest something

Comment: [\[MSDN\]: SetupAPI Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376947(v=vs.85).aspx) could be a starting point. I remember that in the past I did something similar (I'm not sure about this exact property), but I don't have the code right now. Would it make sense to take a look? Note that it might require a hybrid approach between _SetupAPI_ and reading from the driver _.inf_ file.

Comment: yes you are right , setupDi can be used but i am not able to access this particular property using that @CristiFati

Answer (score 0):

Windows information can be retrieve using registry or WMI. I would suggest you to retrieve driver information from registry.

> HKLM\SYSTEM\DriverDatabase

Another way to read system information is using [WMI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558(v=vs.85).aspx).

Hope this will help.

Comment: I didn't find as such entry in registry .There must be some API .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989993/how-to-get-device-properties-in-windows-in-c this link could be helpful if someone is not able to decode .