# How to get the driver version of a display device?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc

how could we get the driver version of a display device programmingly?
   we can get information of the Display Device by running the command "DxDiag", including (1) the card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX745;(2) Manufacturer:(3) NVIDIA, and the Driver name;(4) the driver File version:23.21.13.9077 (this number of 23.21.13.9077 is exactly what we want).

the program need to tell the least driver version number of a display device in case of program crash. this driver version leads to program crash. here i want to hint the user to upgrading driver version in case of program crashing.

Edit:
   Actually the driver version of the display device is different from the OpenGL version (which can retrieved by using glGetString(GL_VERSION)).

Here [the link](https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P00004GRwwbSAD/why-the-graphics-driver-cannot-support-api-wglcreatecontext?language=en_US) describe the problem in details if you have further interest.

any help is very thankful!

Comment: You might want to take a look at this: [Microsoft.DirectX.Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/bb318763(v%3dvs.85))

Comment: You might also try spawning an OpenGL context and asking for the driver version, or ask the driver directly using [NVAPI](https://docs.nvidia.com/gameworks/content/gameworkslibrary/coresdk/nvapi/group__driverapi.html#gac61128f1fd3fce02b653ef1c5cfa2a39)

Comment: you can query interface via `CM_Get_Device_Interface_List` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_DISPLAY_ADAPTER`, than from interface get device id via `CM_Get_Device_Interface_Property` with `DEVPKEY_Device_InstanceId` + `CM_Locate_DevNode`. and then do several query of devnode via `CM_Get_DevNode_Property`. say for `DEVPKEY_Device_DriverVersion`, `DEVPKEY_Device_DriverDesc`, `DEVPKEY_Device_Manufacturer`,...

Answer (score 1):

> How to get the driver version of a display device?

This, I believe, can be done using `setupapi.h`

https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/

and see also this subpage:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdibuilddriverinfolist

See also this answer, that is somewhat related to how you 'navigate' the API:

[How to get device properties in windows in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5989993/how-to-get-device-properties-in-windows-in-c)